# How to call the same function sequentially with different arguments while using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I would like to call the function `example` multiple times with different arguments, while using `setTimeout` inside `logic`. I want this to be sequential (after the first call is made and finished, the second call can begin, and so on). In the following code snippet, `example` seems to be going through both arrays element-wise:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

function logic(i, arr) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }, (i + 1) * 300);
}

function example(arr) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        logic(i, arr);
    }

}

setTimeout(() => {
    example(arr1)
}, 3000);
setTimeout(() => {
    example(arr2)
}, 3000);
```

```
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

I am aware that I could just set the timer of the second call to 6 seconds for example, and it will work, but I wonder:

Is there is another way to find out that the call to `example` is done and then trigger the next one? Without statically defining some delays and maybe even without `setTimeout`?

The expected output would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logic` needs to let the caller know when it's done, then example needs to let the caller know when it's done. Promises will help you here.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

function logic(i, arr) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        resolve();
    }, (i + 1) * 300);
  });
}

async function example(arr) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        await logic(i, arr);
    }

}

(async function() {
  await example(arr1);
  await example(arr2);
})();
```